# Assembly TASM large model procedure (called from C) matrix loop

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

Wrote a procedure in Assembly 8086, which will receive from C the following:

```
int *matrix[size], int size, int *num1, int *num2.
```

I wrote it first as small model, it worked great, when I turned it to large model it stopped working correctly, I tried changing the loops count, the "rows pointer" add by 4, the "columns pointer" add by 2 (tried both add by 4 and the opposite).

The procedure is supposed to check the minimum (in absolute value), meaning the smallest |x-y|.
For example, the procedure will get N number, subtract it from all other numbers and always save the minimum of |x-y|. Afterwards it will move N one number ahead, and check the same with the rest of the numbers until all matrix have been checked.

C Code (can't change anything in this one):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    extern int getDiffMin(int *mat[], int size , int *num1 , int *num2);

        int main()
        {
            int 

diff , i, j , num1 , num2;
        int **mat = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * 4); 
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            mat[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                mat[i][j] = (i*j) - (5 * i) - (14 * j);
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                printf("%d\t", mat[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        diff = getDiffMin(mat, 4 , &num1 , &num2);
        printf("\nminDiff == |(%d)-(%d)| = %d", num1 , num2 , diff);
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            free(mat[i]);
        free(mat);
        return 0;
    }
```

Assembly code:

```
;extern int getDiffMin(int *mat[], int size , int *num1 , int *num2)
;                      BP+6+8      BP+10      BP+12+14    BP+16+18
;
.MODEL LARGE ;Pointers size = 4 bytes
.DATA
    I       DW  ?
    J       DW  ?
    N       DW  ?
    Min     DW  ?
    TempI   DW  ?
    TempJ   DW  ?
    Counter DW  ?
    Two     DW  2
.CODE
.386
PUBLIC _getDiffMin
_getDiffMin PROC FAR
Start:
    PUSH BP ;Save BP's current value
    MOV BP,SP
    PUSH SI
    PUSH DI
    PUSH CX
    PUSH ES
    PUSH GS
    MOV CX,WORD PTR [BP+10] ;CX point to size (matrix of size*size)
    MOV SI,WORD PTR [BP+6] ;SI point to pointer in *mat[] (points to rows)
    MOV ES,WORD PTR [BP+8] ;Segment of *mat[]
    MOV DI,WORD PTR ES:[SI] ;DI point to value in *mat[] (points to columns, with first pointer on rows so gives value)
    MOV ES,WORD PTR ES:[SI+2] ;Segment of *mat[]
    MOV I,0 ;Rows index counter
    MOV J,0 ;Columns index counter
    MOV Counter,CX
    ADD Counter,CX ;Counter for loop
FirstGetN: ;Get number to check with all other numbers
    MOV AX,WORD PTR ES:[DI] ;AX has value which DI is pointing to
    MOV N,AX
FirstSubNumbers:
    ADD DI,2 ;Point to next column
    MOV AX,WORD PTR ES:[DI] ;AX has value one column ahead from N
    SUB AX,N
    CMP AX,0
    JG Continue1
    NEG AX ;Convert sub result to positive
Continue1:
    MOV Min,AX ;Save minimum difference in Min for loop with compare ahead
    MOV SI,WORD PTR [BP+12] ;SI point to *num1 (in case first check had the minimum difference)
    MOV GS,WORD PTR [BP+14] ;Segment of *num1
    MOV AX,N
    MOV GS:[SI],AX ;*num1 = N
    MOV SI,WORD PTR [BP+16] ;SI point to *num2
    MOV GS,WORD PTR [BP+18] ;Segment of *num2
    MOV AX,WORD PTR ES:[DI] ;AX = second number
    MOV GS:[SI],AX ;*num2 = second number
GetN:
    MOV SI,WORD PTR [BP+6] 
    MOV ES,WORD PTR [BP+8] 
    ADD SI,I ;Add needed row
    MOV DI,WORD PTR ES:[SI]
    MOV ES,WORD PTR ES:[SI+2]
    ADD DI,J ;Add needed column
    MOV AX,WORD PTR ES:[DI]
    MOV N,AX ;N contains number being checked with others
    MOV AX,I ;In order to move from N location forward (numbers before were checked during the loop)
    MOV TempI,AX
    MOV AX,J
    MOV TempJ,AX
    MOV AX,Counter
    CMP TempJ,AX ;Meaning it's in last column
    JE Fix
AddJ:
    ADD TempJ,2 ;Move to next column
    JMP SubNumbers
Fix:
    MOV TempJ,0 ;Back to first column
    ADD TempI,4 ;New row
SubNumbers:
    MOV SI,WORD PTR [BP+6] 
    MOV ES,WORD PTR [BP+8] 
    ADD SI,TempI
    MOV DI,WORD PTR ES:[SI]
    MOV ES,WORD PTR ES:[SI+2]
    ADD DI,TempJ
    MOV AX,WORD PTR ES:[DI] ;AX contains number to check with N
    MOV BX,N ;Move N to BX in order to save N's value
    SUB BX,AX ;BX (N) -= AX
    CMP BX,0
    JG Continue2
    Neg BX
Continue2:
    MOV AX,Min
    SUB AX,BX ;Substract former minimum and current sub result
    CMP AX,0 ;To check which one is bigger
    JLE Continue3 ;If BX > AX 
    MOV Min,BX ;Else, Min=BX
    MOV SI,WORD PTR [BP+12] ;SI point to *num1
    MOV GS,WORD PTR [BP+14] ;Segment of *num1
    MOV AX,N
    MOV GS:[SI],AX ;*num1 = N
    MOV SI,WORD PTR [BP+16] ;SI point to *num2
    MOV GS,WORD PTR [BP+18] ;Segment of *num2
    MOV AX,WORD PTR ES:[DI] ;AX = second number
    MOV GS:[SI],AX ;*num2 = second number
Continue3:
    MOV AX,Counter
    CMP TempJ,AX ;Meaning all columns were checked 
    JNE AddJ
    MOV TempJ,0 ;Else, go to first column
    ADD TempI,4 ;Next row
    MUL Two
    CMP TempI,AX ;Meaning all rows (and columns) were checked 
    JNE SubNumbers
    MOV AX,Counter
    ADD J,2 ;Move to next column with N number (J is pointing to INT so advance 2 bytes)
    CMP J,AX
    JNE GetN
Fix2:
    MOV J,0
    MOV AX,Counter
    MUL Two
    ADD I,4
    CMP I,AX ;If all rows have been checked with N number (I is pointing to pointer so jumps of 4 byte, LARGE MODEL)
    JE Finish
    JMP GetN
Finish:
    MOV AX,Min ;Save value to return
    POP GS ;POP by LIFO order
    POP ES
    POP CX 
    POP DI
    POP SI
    POP BP
    RET ;AX, IP and CS
_getDiffMin ENDP
END Start
```

Thank you.

Comment: "None worked" is not a good problem description. What happened? Use your debugger (if you have tasm you probably have td too) to single step the code and see where it does something unexpected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is I needed to add 2 for the "loops" since 'size' (brought from C Code) start it's count from 0.

Here's the ASM code:

```
;extern int getDiffMin(int *mat[], int size , int *num1 , int *num2)
;                      BP+6+8      BP+10      BP+12+14    BP+16+18
;
.MODEL LARGE ;Pointers size = 4 bytes
.DATA
    I       DW  ?
    J       DW  ?
    N       DW  ?
    Min     DW  ?
    TempI   DW  ?
    TempJ   DW  ?
    Counter DW  ?
    Two     DW  2
.CODE
.386
PUBLIC _getDiffMin
_getDiffMin PROC FAR
Start:
    PUSH BP ;Save BP's current value
    MOV BP,SP
    PUSH SI
    PUSH DI
    PUSH CX
    PUSH ES
    PUSH GS
    MOV CX,WORD PTR [BP+10] ;CX point to size (matrix of size*size)
    MOV SI,WORD PTR [BP+6] ;SI point to pointer in *mat[] (points to rows)
    MOV ES,WORD PTR [BP+8] ;Segment of *mat[]
    MOV DI,WORD PTR ES:[SI] ;DI point to value in *mat[] (points to columns, with first pointer on rows so gives value)
    MOV ES,WORD PTR ES:[SI+2] ;Segment of *mat[]
    MOV I,0 ;Rows index counter
    MOV J,0 ;Columns index counter
    MOV Counter,CX
    ADD Counter,2 ;Since size starts from 0, need to make our "loop" bigger by 2
FirstGetN: ;Get number to check with all other numbers
    MOV AX,WORD PTR ES:[DI] ;AX has value which DI is pointing to
    MOV N,AX
FirstSubNumbers:
    ADD DI,2 ;Point to next column
    MOV AX,WORD PTR ES:[DI] ;AX has value one column ahead from N
    SUB AX,N
    CMP AX,0
    JG Continue1
    NEG AX ;Convert sub result to positive
Continue1:
    MOV Min,AX ;Save minimum difference in Min for loop with compare ahead
    MOV SI,WORD PTR [BP+12] ;SI point to *num1 (in case first check had the minimum difference)
    MOV GS,WORD PTR [BP+14] ;Segment of *num1
    MOV AX,N
    MOV GS:[SI],AX ;*num1 = N
    MOV SI,WORD PTR [BP+16] ;SI point to *num2
    MOV GS,WORD PTR [BP+18] ;Segment of *num2
    MOV AX,WORD PTR ES:[DI] ;AX = second number
    MOV GS:[SI],AX ;*num2 = second number
GetN:
    MOV SI,WORD PTR [BP+6] 
    MOV ES,WORD PTR [BP+8] 
    ADD SI,I ;Add needed row
    MOV DI,WORD PTR ES:[SI]
    MOV ES,WORD PTR ES:[SI+2]
    ADD DI,J ;Add needed column
    MOV AX,WORD PTR ES:[DI]
    MOV N,AX ;N contains number being checked with others
    MOV AX,I ;In order to move from N location forward (numbers before were checked during the loop)
    MOV TempI,AX
    MOV AX,J
    MOV TempJ,AX
    MOV AX,Counter
    CMP TempJ,AX ;Meaning it's in last column
    JE Fix
AddJ:
    ADD TempJ,2 ;Move to next column
    JMP SubNumbers
Fix:
    MOV TempJ,0 ;Back to first column
    ADD TempI,4 ;New row
SubNumbers:
    MOV SI,WORD PTR [BP+6] 
    MOV ES,WORD PTR [BP+8] 
    ADD SI,TempI
    MOV DI,WORD PTR ES:[SI]
    MOV ES,WORD PTR ES:[SI+2]
    ADD DI,TempJ
    MOV AX,WORD PTR ES:[DI] ;AX contains number to check with N
    MOV BX,N ;Move N to BX in order to save N's value
    SUB BX,AX ;BX (N) -= AX
    CMP BX,0
    JG Continue2
    Neg BX
Continue2:
    MOV AX,Min
    SUB AX,BX ;Substract former minimum and current sub result
    CMP AX,0 ;To check which one is bigger
    JLE Continue3 ;If BX > AX 
    MOV Min,BX ;Else, Min=BX
    MOV SI,WORD PTR [BP+12] ;SI point to *num1
    MOV GS,WORD PTR [BP+14] ;Segment of *num1
    MOV AX,N
    MOV GS:[SI],AX ;*num1 = N
    MOV SI,WORD PTR [BP+16] ;SI point to *num2
    MOV GS,WORD PTR [BP+18] ;Segment of *num2
    MOV AX,WORD PTR ES:[DI] ;AX = second number
    MOV GS:[SI],AX ;*num2 = second number
Continue3:
    MOV AX,Counter
    CMP TempJ,AX ;Meaning all columns were checked 
    JNE AddJ
    MOV TempJ,0 ;Else, go to first column
    ADD TempI,4 ;Next row
    MOV AX,Counter
    ADD AX,2
    MUL Two
    CMP TempI,AX ;Meaning all rows (and columns) were checked 
    JNE SubNumbers
    MOV AX,Counter
    ADD J,2 ;Move to next column with N number (J is pointing to INT so advance 2 bytes)
    CMP J,AX
    JNE GetN
Fix2:
    MOV J,0
    ADD I,4
    MOV AX,Counter
    ADD AX,2
    MUL Two
    CMP I,AX ;If all rows have been checked with N number (I is pointing to pointer so jumps of 4 byte, LARGE MODEL)
    JE Finish
    JMP GetN
Finish:
    MOV AX,Min ;Save value to return
    POP GS ;POP by LIFO order
    POP ES
    POP CX 
    POP DI
    POP SI
    POP BP
    RET ;AX, IP and CS
_getDiffMin ENDP
END Start
```